# GNOME - Scale Windows to factor less than 1

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

Is there any way to set the scale factor to less than 1? I feel the windows are too big and I wish to make them smaller so that I can have more room on my screen. Gnome tweak tool doesn't allow me to set it less than 1.

Comment: It seems you can only set whole numbers for the scaling. However, here is an article that explains how to set it using xrandr https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#How_to_use_non-whole_numbers

Comment: Not really a solution but in Unity you can by heading to Display section in system settings. You might want to check if there is such setting in GNOME. Note: I completely agree with you that everything is too big, especially compared to Windows, so I set the scaling to 0.875.

Answer (score 0):

On debian, but not ubuntu ... apparently.  I'm looking for the answer myself.

edit: just used this in the dconf editor:

org>>gnome>>desktop>>interface>>text-scaling-factor

I set it to .8 ... it seems do do the same thing because the bars are scaled by the text.